# how i could print multiple delimiter word using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a awk with regex delimiter I need to extract word of firstname and last name , but this command not works

```
        awk -v    OFS="\t" -v FS='firstName": "|",[^+]*lastName": "|",   "' '{sum[$1]+=$2;} {print  $1,$2}' sumacomando
```

```html
"firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

I need to print

```html
gdrgo,222
beto,111
beto,111
beto2,555
beto2,444
gdrgo,222
beto2,444
```

please help me

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  Also, why are you determined to do this with Awk?

Comment: yes I read a post that is possible use multiple delimiter but I dont know why my command not works

Comment: awk -v    OFS="\t" -v FS='firstName": "|",[^+]*lastName": "|",   "' '{sum[$1]+=$2;} {print  $1,$2}' sumacomando

Comment: Are you just trying to print the values associated with the firstname and lastname tags?

Comment: yes  I use this delimiter  FS='firstName": "|",[^+]*lastName": "|",   "' '  but I think i made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is a CSV so the way to handle that is [GNU awk for FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content), and your output is also a CSV so setting OFS to a tab wouldn't make sense. In general when you have ANY file that contains name->value mappings the simplest, most robust way to handle it is to first create an array of those mappings (`f[]` below) and then you can print or otherwise manipulate your data by using it's names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,t,/[[:space:]":]+/)
        f[t[2]] = t[3]
    }
    print f["firstName"], f["lastName"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
gdrgo,222
beto,111
beto,111
beto2,555
beto2,444
gdrgo,222
beto2,444
```

Answer (score -1):

this command works

```
awk -v OFS='"' -v FS='Name": "' '{i = index($3, "\"");i2 = index($4, "\""); print substr($3, 0, i) ";" substr($4, 0, i2) }' sumacomando
```

```
gdrgo,222
beto,111
beto,111
beto2,555
beto2,444
gdrgo,222
beto2,444
```

Comment: This post is not an answer and seems completely unrelated to your question. As such you should delete it so it doesn't just linger here adding no value and gathering downvotes.

Comment: i put a in this post that not is the answer  ;I just wanted to give you an idea of how you could solve

Comment: I correct the command