# Why does my Awk command filter my text without a for loop but not when a for loop is added?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to filter "5" and use "for" for print 3 times

This is the command without `for` loop:

```
awk -v OFS='"' -v FS='Name": "'  'match($2, /5"/){print $0}' sumacomando
```

This is the command with `for` loop:

```
awk -v OFS='"' -v FS='Name": "'  '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {match($2, /5"/); {print $0}}}' sumacomando
```

This not filter only print 3 times

I'm trying to filter "5" and use `for` to print 3 times.

```
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "6","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

```shell
awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {match($2, /5"/)  ;{  print $0}}}' sumacomando
```

This is my output

```
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "6","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "6","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "6","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

This is my expected output

```
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

This is my code without `for` loop:

```
awk -v OFS='"' -v FS='Name": "'  'match($2, /5"/){print $0}' sumacomando
```

How I could solve this?

Comment: if the input is changed to NDJSON (it's very close to it) then you could use something like jsonfilter and jsonmap probably

https://github.com/jsonlines/guide#jsonfilter
https://github.com/jsonlines/guide#jsonmap

Comment: you should stop setting FS creatively.  It's better to follow best practices and idioms everybody already agreed on.  You have been asking variations of the same question but not adapting the answers provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already told you how to approach problems like this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753485/1745001 and just add a line to that answer that says:

```
f["fechaName"]==5{for (i=1;i<=3;i++) print}
```

Look:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,t,/[[:space:]":]+/)
        f[t[2]] = t[3]
    }
}
f["fechaName"]==5 { for (i=1;i<=3;i++) print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

wrt debugging the script in your question, you wrote:

```
{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {match($2, /5"/)  ;{  print $0}}}
```

which says "loop 3 times, calling match() but doing nothing with the result of that match() and unconditionally printing the current line". You probably meant to write:

```
match($2, /5"/) { for(i=1;i<=3;i++) print }
```

but of course that approach is extremely fragile as it will produce false matches for various input values and so you should definitely NOT use it.

Comment: hi I understand but I need more short solution

Comment: Then edit your question to include that extremely important requirement along with a statement of how many characters long the solution has to be to satisfy it plus why that is a consideration. If all you want is something short that produces that output then you could use `grep -h '"5"' file file file`.

Comment: i put my code here olny i need to know why not works as expected                                             awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {match($2, /5"/)  ;{  print $0}}}' sumacomando

Comment: awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {match($2, /5"/)  ;{  print $0}}}' sumacomando

Comment: this is my code whitout for awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      'match($2, /5"/){print $0}' sumacomando

Comment: awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'      'match($2, /5"/){print $0}' sumacomando

Comment: Seriously - please edit your question to clearly state what your actual question is, whether that's how to do what you want sensibly, or how to do want you want briefly, or just help debugging a script or something else. Right now it's just not clear what you're asking for help with.

Comment: Again - do you want the right solution to your problem (if so see my answer) or do you want the briefest script that will output what you want or something else? You posted one script in your question and a bunch of other scripts in the comments above. If you're asking for help debugging the scripts in the comments above then include at least one of them in your question and tell us in what way it's not satisfying your requirements (wrong output, no output, error messages, core dump, something else?).

Answer (score 2):

Short? I even removed the spaces:

```
$ awk '$2~/^"5"/{for(;++i<=3;)print}' file
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```