# awk command print but not print in order?

Tags: awk

I use this awk command

```
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "6","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

```
 awk  -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'     '{ for( i=0; i<=4; i++ ) if( match($2,i) ) print $0 }'   sumacomando
```

and output this

```
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

I expected this

```
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

HOw I could solve this

Please help me

Comment: Its not the same question

Comment: Please dont close

Comment: There are people who only use awk to organize data for different reasons

Comment: awk without external commands

Comment: ITs not the same for  the awk for not print correctly

Comment: the solution that you posted its not compatible with all version of awk

Comment: not compatible with mawk , nawk and awk

Comment: Ok many thanks what happens is that i have searched for a crossplatform language to process data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not clear what your real goal is. Are you trying to find all lines where the fechaName is less than 5 and sort them? If so that'd be:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='\t' '$4<5{print $4, NR, $0}' file | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

The above will work with any POSIX awk, sort, and cut.

To do what you want entirely within one awk script would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "\"" }
$4 < 5 {
    if ( !seen[$4]++ ) {
        keys[++numKeys] = $4
    }
    keyLines[$4,++numLines[$4]] = $0
}
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines[key]; lineNr++) {
            print keyLines[key,lineNr]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

The above will work with any modern awk, including all POSIX awks, mawk, gawk, tawk, and nawk. The only negative to it is it stores all of the matching lines in memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer i have given you an upvote

What happens is that i wanted to use nawk to use it on windows, linux and mac

But without using sort because it is not like transporting it natively to these three platform

That's why I chose the first answer because I initially asked what was wrong with my command

And having no better answer was the only thing he could do

Comment: `nawk` is a very old, pre-POSIX awk. Are you sure that;s what you have to deal with and you can't use a modern/POSIX awk?

Comment: The problem is that I could not make it run natively on windows

Comment: only using cygwins and this is problematic

Comment: nawk its compile in windows and mac

Comment: I'm about 99% sure there's a native Windows version of gawk. Ditto for mac.

Comment: Ok I did not know that there was a version of gawk for windows

I confess that I also liked the idea of being able to use any version of awk

Since each version of awk has its advantages

Comment: I added an awk script that will do what you want in any awk (except of course old, broken awk stored as /bin/awk on Solaris).

Answer (score 2):

With given input, below [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) should work, no need of calling `match` function and setting `OFS`

```
awk -F'"' '$4 <= 4' file  | sort -t'"' -nk4
```

**Explanation**

- Set field sep as `"`
- if 4th field is less than or equal to 4 then print current record of file
- sort by 4th field, where field separator being `"`

**Input**

```
$ cat file
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "6","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'"' '$4 <= 4' file  | sort -t'"' -nk4 
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "3","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

Comment: You'd need to add the `-s` option to `sort` to guarantee retaining input order but then i THINK it'd become GNU-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 awk -F'[": ,]' '$6 <= 4' Input_file | sort -k2
```

**Explanation:** I am making field separators as (" : , space) by using -F option of awk, then I am checking field 6th(which will be 2nd if you consider by default awk's field separator as a space) is equal to 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, if this condition is TRUE then it will print the current line(awk works on condition then action pattern, so here condition is mentioned but I didn't mention any action so by default print will happen of current line), then I am sorting the output of it according to 2nd field.

Comment: I need to know because awk not print in order when I print for 1 to 3                          this print in order but 1 to 4 the four print in the same order

Comment: @victorhernandezzero: Obviously it will not print in sorting order because in your Input_file shown 2nd last line is having 4 as second field and last line again 3. So when you given condition from 0 to 4 match then last both lines will be satisfying the condition and it will print them, in case you put only 0 to 3 in loop then 2nd last line will not satisfy the condition and last line will come after the 3 matching line(means 3rd from last line) and it will look like it is sorting the data which is not the case actually(it simply printing with condition). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes Help me but there is some way I can use a for statement to print this data in order

Comment: awk  -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'     '{ for( i=0; i<=4; i++ ) if( match($2,i) ) print $0 }'   sumacomando

Comment: No you are not testing if it `is equal to 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4`, you're testing if it **contains** any of those digits so it'd match `9627` for example. @victorhernandezzero not sure why you're still fighting against using the robust solutions you were given twice previously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42753485/1745001 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/42755036/1745001.

Comment: Thanks a TON Ed Morton, I have changed it now.

Answer (score -1):

well ; I cant do this question  using awk simple command  without external
commands this is possible using associative array but its a bit more complicate BUT with a simple while  external command works well for me

```
x=1 


while [ $x -le 8 ]; do   awk -v     OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'   -v x=$x     'match($2,x)  {  print $0}'    sumacomando >> sumacomando4   ;x=$(( $x + 1 )); done
```

In any way any language includes as sentences